# Creating a class whose objects can be mathematically combined into objects that have appropriate derived methods

Tags: python, class, operator-overloading

Say I have a class as follows:

```
import math

class RegularPolygon(object):
    def __init__(self, num_sides, side_len):
        self._num_sides = num_sides
        self._side_len = side_len

    def perimeter(self):
        return self._num_sides * self._side_len

    def apothem(self):
        return self._side_len / (2. * math.tan(math.pi / self._num_sides))

    def area(self):
        return self.perimeter() * self.apothem() / 2.
```

That lets me define a few objects as follows:

```
unit_square = RegularPolygon(4, 1)
unit_pentagon = RegularPolygon(5, 1)
unit_octagon = RegularPolygon(8, 1)
```

What I would like to have is the ability to combine objects of this class using any standard mathematical operation (let's say at least `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, and `**`).  And I would want the result of any such combination to be an object whose methods would return the calculation performed on the results of methods called on the constituent objects.

So, for example, if I wrote:

```
a_pair_of_squares = unit_square + unit_square
```

I would want that to be some kind of `PolygonCollection` object.  And I would want

```
a_pair_of_squares.area()
```

to return

```
unit_square.area() + unit_square.area()
```

and similarly, if I defined

```
a_shape_mashup = (unit_square + (2 * unit_pentagon)) / unit_octagon
```

I would want

```
a_shape_mashup.perimeter()
```

to return

```
(unit_square.perimeter() + (2 * unit_pentagon.perimeter())) / unit_octagon.perimeter()
```

and

```
a_shape_mashup.area()
```

should return

```
(unit_square.area() + (2 * unit_pentagon.area())) / unit_octagon.area()
```

Is this possible?  What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Python provides operator overloading for your custom classes. See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Comment: I'm familiar with operator overloading.  In fact, I've got this working up to the point of being able to handle linear combinations of objects (because a linear combination of linear combinations is itself a linear combination), but I hadn't figured out how to generalize this to the more complete case of handing all the infix operations gracefully. I was hoping to find a solution that did that.